# Download Images One By One with url using SDWebimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I need to Download images from `Array` of Url's, one by one and Display all at a Time.
Ex. I have an array of 10 URL's and I need to Download image One By One only, and display at a time.
I am Using `SDWebImage` for Download Images.
Please Help me.

Thanks.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: `Swift` or `Objective-C`?

Comment: @Nirav , i am using Objective-C

Comment: @PayalManiyar i am Tried to Load images From Array Using SDWebImages and Want to Store that image One by One in another Array.

Comment: Paste  your code here.

Comment: What you mean to say? You are saying to place images and asking for download.

Comment: @PayalManiyar [imgVideo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kThubnailImagePath,[[_videoArray valueForKey:@"video_image"] objectAtIndex:i - 1]]] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
            {
                // store in another array
            }];

Comment: Add code in your question using "edit".

Comment: @EktaMakadiya Hi Ekta, i want to download image from array and add in second array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
-(void)downloadImage {
     if self.urlArray.count > 0) {
         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.urlArray firstObject]];
         SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
         [manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                  options:0
                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                     // progression tracking code
                 }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                     if (image) {
                         [self.imageArray addObject:image];
                         [self.urlArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                         [self downloadImage];
                     }
                     else {
                         [self downloadImage]; //try download once again
                     }
                 }];
     }
     else {
         NSLog(@"All Images are downloaded do what u want")
     }
}
```

**Note:-** Here `urlArray` is array of string url and `imageArray` array contain all the image that you have download.

call this method after you have got all the string url in `urlArray`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Your url does not contain image that was the issue.

Comment: Thanks Nirav, I got the Solution.

Comment: What you have try?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you download image as independent image with SDWebImage in Swift

```
import SDWebImage

let downloader = SDWebImageManager()

downloader.imageDownloader?.downloadImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), options: .highPriority, progress: { 
        (receivedSize, expectedSize, url) in
        // image is being downloading and you can monitor progress here
            }, completed: { (downloadedImage, data, error, success) in
                print(downloadedImage, data, success)
                //image is downloaded and ready to use
            })
```